# Python app running correctly on local environment but not on Azure

Tags: python, azure-web-app-service, microsoft-teams, langchain

I have deployed python web app for teams  and deployed it to azure and It giving me following error. The libraries that I'm using with web app version are same. When I checking the error log following errors were there. I cannot figure out what causing this issue. Everything is similar in both versions.The local version is working perfectly fine and there are no any errors.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_adapter.py", line 128, in run_pipeline
    return await self._middleware.receive_activity_with_status(
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 69, in receive_activity_with_status
    return await self.receive_activity_internal(context, callback)
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botbuilder/core/middleware_set.py", line 79, in receive_activity_internal
    return await callback(context)
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/bots/state_management_bot.py", line 46, in on_turn
    await super().on_turn(turn_context)
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/botbuilder/core/activity_handler.py", line 70, in on_turn
    await self.on_message_activity(turn_context)
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/bots/state_management_bot.py", line 93, in on_message_activity
    response = chat(turn_context.activity.text, user_profile.user_id)
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/ai_models/openaifunc.py", line 139, in chat
    response = mrkl.run(userMsg)
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 505, in run
    return self(args[0], callbacks=callbacks, tags=tags, metadata=metadata)[
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 310, in call
    raise e
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/chains/base.py", line 304, in call
    self._call(inputs, run_manager=run_manager)
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 1146, in _call
    next_step_output = self._take_next_step(
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/agents/agent.py", line 996, in _take_next_step
    observation = tool.run(
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/tools/base.py", line 365, in run
    raise e
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/tools/base.py", line 337, in run
    self._run(*tool_args, run_manager=run_manager, **tool_kwargs)
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/tools/base.py", line 510, in _run
    self.func(
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/tools/base.py", line 449, in call
    return self.run(tool_input, callbacks=callbacks)
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/tools/base.py", line 365, in run
    raise e
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/tools/base.py", line 337, in run
    self._run(*tool_args, run_manager=run_manager, **tool_kwargs)
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/tools/base.py", line 631, in _run
    else self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/ai_models/customTools.py", line 356, in productdescriptions
    product_info = productdata(query)
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/ai_models/customTools.py", line 366, in productdata
    docsearch = Pinecone.from_existing_index(indexname, embedding)
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/vectorstores/pinecone.py", line 437, in from_existing_index
    pinecone_index = cls.get_pinecone_index(index_name, pool_threads)
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/langchain/vectorstores/pinecone.py", line 354, in get_pinecone_index
    indexes = pinecone.list_indexes()  # checks if provided index exists
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pinecone/manage.py", line 185, in list_indexes
    response = api_instance.list_indexes()
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pinecone/core/client/api_client.py", line 776, in call
    return self.callable(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pinecone/core/client/api/index_operations_api.py", line 1132, in __list_indexes
    return self.call_with_http_info(**kwargs)
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pinecone/core/client/api_client.py", line 838, in call_with_http_info
    return self.api_client.call_api(
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pinecone/core/client/api_client.py", line 413, in call_api
    return self.__call_api(resource_path, method,
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pinecone/core/client/api_client.py", line 200, in __call_api
    response_data = self.request(
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pinecone/core/client/api_client.py", line 439, in request
    return self.rest_client.GET(url,
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pinecone/core/client/rest.py", line 236, in GET
    return self.request("GET", url,
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pinecone/core/client/rest.py", line 202, in request
    r = self.pool_manager.request(method, url,
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 74, in request
    return self.request_encode_url(
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 96, in request_encode_url
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 376, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 714, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 415, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 244, in request
    super(HTTPConnection, self).request(method, url, body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/opt/python/3.10.12/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1283, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/python/3.10.12/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1324, in _send_request
    self.putheader(hdr, value)
  File "/tmp/8dbd9c87f8c7bef/antenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 224, in putheader
    _HTTPConnection.putheader(self, header, *values)
  File "/opt/python/3.10.12/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1260, in putheader
    if _is_illegal_header_value(values[i]):
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: We need more information. What is the app supposed to do? Ideally include an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I was able to solve the issue by changing dependencies. It was related with pinecone client.

Comment: @Axen_Rangs - Please post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was resolved. I was able to solve the issue by changing dependencies. It was related with pinecone client.